# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8.dll' - The specified module could not be found

Tags: xampp, instantclient

I want to use php oci8 function , but I got this error

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8.dll' - The specified module could not be found. (C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache)
```

I have follow all this step

How to enable Oracle Connection to PHP on XAMPP

1. Install XAMPP 1.7.3 on your Windows. (Please remove the old version of XAMPP and please delete `C:\xampp` BEFORE installing the new version of XAMPP).
2. Extract InstantClient to `C:\instantclient_11_2` folder.
3. Open system setting at Start Menu > My Computer(right click on the icon) > Select Properties > Advanced Tabs > Environment Variables.
4. Add to ‘System Variables’ by clicking ‘New’ button and insert the following values:
   a.  Variable Name : `PATH`
   b.  Variable Value  : `c:\instantclient_11_2`
5. Click OK to accept new modification.
6. Open `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` by using notepad.
7. Find string `oci8` and remove the `;` symbol at the beginning of the string line.
8. Save and Exit.
9. Restart you laptop/pc to accept new modification on xampp.

I setup at Window Server 2008 R2 64bit.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You have to update your environment variable `PATH` in `System Variable`by adding `C:\instantclient_11_2` and not by creating a new one. You should only restart 'XAMPP' and not restarting your machine

Comment: I have done that by same result

Comment: try this : create a new environment variable **ORACLE_HOME** = **PATH_TO_INSTANTCLIENT**, and restart your XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever try to copy the files orannzsbb11.dll , oci.dll and oraociei11.dll to c:\windows\system32 ? try it. It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to face  the same issue.But as this link suggests
[OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. When i try to connect my oracle database in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734100/ocienvnlscreate-failed-when-i-try-to-connect-my-oracle-database-in-php)

I copy paste everything inside instantclient to System32 folder.

this way worked for me.